# Make bootstrap menu 'floating' and fixed width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I'm trying to use bootstrap but have a few questions about the navbar. At the moment it's fixed to the top but i'd like there to be some padding between the nav and the top of the page, as though the nav was floating. I'd also like the nav to be the same width as the content. Any ideas how this is possible?

Thanks!(code below)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Explore Canterbury</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">

      <!-- Static navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div id="navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want some space between the navbar and the to of the page you could add a new class or add the style to the existing navbar class. Something like so:

```
.navbar {
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

We will need more details on what you mean by making it the same width as content. Right now you have the navbar wrapped in a div with a container class that is causing it not to be the full width.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual page, you do have the ability to add your own stylesheet and then create your own styles to add in padding, margins, widths, etc to customize anything bootstrap is not doing without tweaking the bootstrap style sheet. If you post the link to your page, I might be able to give you a clearer answer.